# scala process never finishes in IDEA

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, jvm, spinalhdl

When I running a SpinalHDL simulation program, the process is done but never exit. That is, "Process finished with exit code 0" never showed up. I have to shutdown the IDEA to end the process. How is it?

```
import spinal.core._
import spinal.sim._
import spinal.core.sim._

import scala.util.Random


//MyTopLevel's testbench
object MyTopLevelSim {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    SimConfig.withWave.doSim(new MyTopLevel){dut =>
      //Fork a process to generate the reset and the clock on the dut
      dut.clockDomain.forkStimulus(period = 10)

      var modelState = 0
      for(idx <- 0 to 99){
        //Drive the dut inputs with random values
        dut.io.cond0 #= Random.nextBoolean()
        dut.io.cond1 #= Random.nextBoolean()

        //Wait a rising edge on the clock
        dut.clockDomain.waitRisingEdge()

        //Check that the dut values match with the reference model ones
        val modelFlag = modelState == 0 || dut.io.cond1.toBoolean
        assert(dut.io.state.toInt == modelState)
        assert(dut.io.flag.toBoolean == modelFlag)

        //Update the reference model value
        if(dut.io.cond0.toBoolean) {
          modelState = (modelState + 1) & 0xFF
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Belows are the infomation in Console. The process is never ending...

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57888', transport: 'socket'
[Runtime] SpinalHDL v1.6.0    git head : 73c8d8e2b86b45646e9d0b2e729291f2b65e6be3
[Runtime] JVM max memory : 4070.0MiB
[Runtime] Current date : 2023.06.21 15:11:03
[Progress] at 0.000 : Elaborate components
[Progress] at 0.611 : Checks and transforms
[Progress] at 0.685 : Generate Verilog
[Done] at 0.755
[Progress] Simulation workspace in C:\Users\xxx\spinalhdl_home\test_new\.\simWorkspace\MyTopLevel
[Progress] Verilator compilation started
[Progress] Verilator compilation done in 4973.795 ms
[Progress] Start MyTopLevel test simulation with seed 835369353
done1
[Done] Simulation done in 20.747 ms
```

Find the problem in SpinalHDL simulation with verilator in my own PC, while in others' PCs it is done well. How to end the process as a general program process?

Comment: Does it work if you build/run the project from the command line outside of the IDE? To better understand what causes the problem please upload a project sample at https://uploads.jetbrains.com and share the UploadID here

Comment: @Egor Klepikov: Thanks for reply. Running from the cmd is the same as IDE. The uploadID is 2023_06_22_qA3uoJmdcDpBECwyLQgBJU. By the way, JDK 17.07, scala 2.12.15, windows 10, sbt 1.5.5.

Comment: If you face the same issue running from command line then it's not related to IDE.